# How to calculate number of position fixed div tag while printing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var bottom = 0; /* Position of first page number - 0 for bottom of first page */
var pagNum = 2; /* First sequence - Second number */
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* For each 10 paragraphs, this function: clones the h3 with a new page number */
  $("p:nth-child(10n)").each(function() {
    bottom -= 100;
    botString = bottom.toString();
    var $counter = $('h3.pag1').clone().removeClass('pag1');
    $counter.css("bottom", botString + "vh");
    numString = pagNum.toString();
    $counter.addClass("pag" + numString);
    ($counter).insertBefore('.insert');
    pagNum = parseInt(numString);
    pagNum++; /* Next number */
  });
  var pagTotal = $('.pag').length; /* Gets the total amount of pages by total classes of paragraphs */
  pagTotalString = pagTotal.toString();
  $("h3[class^=pag]").each(function() {
    /* Gets the numbers of each classes and pages */
    var numId = this.className.match(/\d+/)[0];
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('h3.pag' + numId + '::before', 'content: "Page ' + numId + ' of ' + pagTotalString + '";');
  });
});

$('.print').on('click', function() {
  window.print();
  return false;
});
```

The code above will add one to page number every 10 `<p>` tag. E.g.

```
// if one <p> tag
Page 1 of 1

// if ten <p> tag
Page 1 of 10
```

I have a position fixed `<div>` tag, where will be displayed on top of every printed page. I want to get the number of position fixed `<div>` tag, whenever it is displayed on next printed page.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will grab all `<div>` elements, and filter out all of those without `position: fixed`.

jQuery's `.css()` getter makes use of JavaScript's [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), therefore it works for both inline *and* CSS-applied styles.

```js
var fixedDivCount = $("div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('position') == 'fixed';
}).length;

console.log(fixedDivCount);
```

```css
.two {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: fixed;">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div></div>
```